# How to get the number of bytes read from cache in C

Tags: c

I have a simple C program that open the file in a loop:

```
for(i = 1; i <= loopCount; ++i)
{

   FILE *fp;
   char buff[255];

   fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
   fgets(buff, 255, (FILE*)fp);
   /* do something */
   fclose(fp);
}
```

I want to know each time how many bytes read from cache and how many bytes read from disk and log it. (I run it in Ubuntu 16.04 if it matter) is there any way I could find that? has any one any idea?

Comment: Your question is not well specified. Are you asking for a way to determine how many bytes had to be read from disk to satisfy your read, including metadata associated with the directory and file location? Or are you asking just about the data? Or what? Rather than trying to get you to explain what you want in sufficient detail, which almost never works, instead tell us why you want this information. That way, we can work out what information would be helpful rather than having to ask you a large number of highly complex detailed questions.

Comment: I hardly doubt you will be able to do it... but I would be happy to see someone come out with a solution..

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I just want to know how much of the data read each time was from cache and how many of that came from disk.

Comment: @nbro I don't think there's anything built-in for this, but one can compute the numbers that would be close enough for most practical purposes.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this area but I would try to get hold of the source code for `iotop`, `iostat` and `strace`. I think these programs use the OS calls you need for solving this task.

Comment: @Saeid So, by "data" you mean the actual file contents? Not any file or directory metadata? So you don't care how many bytes were read from disk, just which of the bytes of returned data were read from disk? Also, by cache, I assume you mean the OS disk cache. Is this correct?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long getIORead()
{
    FILE * j = fopen ("/proc/self/io", "r");
    if (j == NULL)
        return -1;

    char buf[256];
    while (fgets(buf, 250, j) != NULL)
        if (strstr(buf, "read_bytes: ") != NULL)
        {
            fclose(j);
            return atol(strchr(buf, ' ') + 1);
        }
    return -1;
}


int main()
{
    unsigned long before, after;
    before = getIORead();

    {
        // code goes here
    }

    after = getIORead();
    printf("Bytes read from disk: %d\n", (int) (after - before));
}
```

It's ugly and lacks good error checking, but this demonstrates how to do it.

Here's the results when the test code reads a file (that hasn't been accessed or modified in ages) that is 4,095,201 bytes long:

> $ ./test
>   Bytes read from disk: 4096000
>   $ ./test
>   Bytes read from disk: 0

As expected, the first read was from the disk, the second read was from the cache.

Comment: Cool answer. It made me search the net and I found this link with some additional info: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html

Comment: @davidSchwartz. The **atol(strchr(buf, ' ') + 1);** always reaturn 0,

Answer (score 0):

Use [`__fbufsize`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/__fbufsize) to retrieve the size of the buffer. This will let you compute the number of bytes retrieved from the buffer vs. the number of bytes retrieved from the file:

```
for(i = 1; i <= loopCount; ++i) {
   FILE *fp;
   char buff[255];
   fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
   size_t bsize = __fbufsize(fp);
   size_t remaining = 0;
   while (fgets(buff, 255, fp)) {
       size_t rsize = strlen(buff);
       if (rsize <= remaining) {
           printf("From buffer: %zu, From file: 0", rsize);
           remaining -= rsize;
       } else {
           size_t additional = rsize-remaining;
           printf("From buffer: %zu, From file: %zu", remaining, additional);
           remaining = bsize - additional % bsize;
       }
       /* do something */
   }
   fclose(fp);
}
```

The idea is to count how much unused bytes we have in the buffer, under the assumption that each time the buffer runs empty it gets refilled to capacity.

The logic is implemented in the `if` conditional inside the loop:

- The first branch describes the situation when the data remaining in the buffer was sufficient to fulfill the read request completely. Here we need to reduce the number of bytes remaining in the buffer.
- The second branch describes the situation when some data (or possibly no data) comes from the buffer, and the `additional` data comes from disk. Note how the code must be careful of the situation when the string that we get back is larger than the buffer (hence the `%` operation).

Comment: Very interesting answer. As far as I can see the code expects that after each `fopen` the first data is always read from the file, correct? I have noticed that opening the same time file two times in a row causes the second file read to be much faster (like the file is already cached). How does that match your code? What am I getting wrong?

Comment: @4386427 This code assumes that opening the file does not initiate reading (hence `remaining = 0`). The reason why subsequent calls to `fopen` of the same file from the same process are faster is that OS is probably caching some file meta-data for some time after a file has been closed, in hopes that the process is going to re-open it soon.

Comment: My understanding (which may be completely wrong as this isn't my area of work) is that the OS will keep all pages of file opened for read-only in page cache (provide that the OS isn't running low on memory). The file contents will stay in memory even after the program terminates and stay there until the OS needs to free memory. So multiple reads of the same file (either from the same program or even from different programs) will not necessarily cause any disk access for read number 2, 3, 4, etc. But then again - I might be all wrong :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight the **bsize** is always 0, ??

Comment: @Saeid That's very odd. Could you give [this example](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.bpxbd00/fbufsize.htm) a try, and let me know what it prints?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I just changed the file name: **The buffer size for text.txt is 0**